# Proper way to denote array data type for phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Which of the following is the proper way to document the return type of this method for phpDocumentor?

**Method 1:**

```
/**
 * @return array Foo array.
 */
public function foo() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
/**
 * @return integer[] Foo array.
 */
public function foo() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Also, are there any IDE implications from either method?

**Edit:**

It appears that both PhpStorm and Netbeans 7.1+ IDEs support the 2nd method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both methods are technically correct, but this one is considered 'better' because it's more specific (`int` and `integer` are interchangeable):

```
@return int[]
```

Documented here:

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html

Comment: Thank you for the link!  I can't believe I missed this.  I want to mark this as the correct answer, except that section 1.4.4 states that either syntax I listed is correct, where your answer specifies only the second is correct (though the 2nd is definitely the most helpful, IMHO).

Comment: Both are correct, but this one considered 'better' because it's more specific. int/integer are interchangable though.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: I appreciate the fact that you took the time to do the edit.

Answer (score 8):

At the moment of writing this answer, these are the accepted ways of [phpDocumentor](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays) (and probably other [PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) implementations) to denote an array:

> 1. **unspecified**, no definition of the contents of the represented array is
>      given. Example: `@return array`
> 2. **specified containing a single type**, the `Type` definition informs the
>      reader of the type of each array element. Only one `Type` is then
>      expected as element for a given array.
>      Example: `@return int[]`
>      Please note that `mixed` is also a single type and with this keyword it
>      is possible to indicate that each array element contains any possible
>      type.
> 3. **specified containing multiple types**, the `Type` definition informs the
>      reader of the type of each array element. Each element can be of any
>      of the given types. Example: `@return (int|string)[]`